# What is the best way to host web applications using .net core and angular?

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, hosting

When hosting web applications, is it good to host a Web API and front end separately eg:.Net Core Web API and Angular 6 project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say it depends on the complexity of the application. If its a small application it wouldn't matter if it is hosted in the same server.

But once the application starts to grow, the front end deployment will require more and more resources and scaling becomes an issue. So its better to have the back-end deployment separate. There are other factors such as security, for example if a layer is hacked only a part of the system will be exposed to the hackers.

Furthermore, if you are planning to call your back-end services from other front ends it is always better to have the back-end separated from the front end in order to manage the network traffic better.